# How to extract elements from a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an image `img = (1024, 2048)` shaped numpy array. I need to take 16 elements (4 x 4) as given in the picture, change them in to a (16, 1) dimension array and save them in a separate array or a list. The total number of (16, 1) dimension arrays will be 1024*2048/16 = 131,072.
I don't know how to make the loop to iterate and accomplish the task. 
Ps: In pic (3×4) array is shown, its actually meant to be (4×4).

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! What did you try exactly to resolve your problem? Consider reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The problem is not the clarity. [I downvoted because no attempt was made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I assume all the elements inside the matrix is 1

[image]

Comment: Don't poste code as an image.... See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks